# how to provide access to private git server to team from other company

Tags: git

Our team located in two different location and client.We want to set up a private git server located inside company network. There is a team located at remote location from different company. we need to provide access to them for few projects. What are best strategy or tools which we should look into. 
I know github will be best suited for this kind of scenario but We are looking for opensource which are freely available with no extra cost.
Please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: http://randyfay.com/content/git-over-ssh-tunnel-through-firewall-or-vpn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is setting up a VPN connection so your client will use to access your network.
The firewall can be configured to allow them to access only the Git server.
In the Git server, you have to manage the permissions and allow client to access only specific repositories.

As mentioned in the comments, a good example is [git-over-ssh-tunnel-through-firewall-or-vpn](http://randyfay.com/content/git-over-ssh-tunnel-through-firewall-or-vpn)

I hope this helps.